# Why is this markdown text rendered so big?

Tags: markdown, github-flavored-markdown

```
----------------
#### goog.closure.dispose
*Related* [goog.events.EventTarget](https://google.github.io/closure-library/api/goog.events.EventTarget.html)\
*Related* [Dispose src](https://github.com/google/closure-library/blob/master/closure/goog/disposable/disposable.js#L166)\
**dispose()**
If dispose was not already called, this calls disposeInternal. It cleans up resources, including socket connection and event handlers.
-----------------
```

The last sentence is rendered in big text and bold. I expected it to be rendered in normal size because it's not enclosed in **. Why is it like this? I'm using github flavor markdown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting `------------` right after a line will regard it as if you were trying to underline the line (e.g. making it a heading).
A single newline is not truly a newline in markdown. You need to add two newlines, other wise it will be considered a new line but of the same paragraph. If that makes any sense.
Anyway, putting at least two newlines before each `---------` should fix your issue.